# Отобразить все фото с instagram в GridLayout

Tags: android, gridview, instagram, instagram-api

Задача: отобразить все фото с `instagram` в виде `GridLayоut` , посоветуйте как это  можно сделать?

Comment: а что конкретно не получается?

Comment: Подключится по API

Comment: Ну, покажите код, который не работает

Answer (score 4, accepted):

используя `API` получить список ссылок на картинки, и загрузить их, но не в `GridLayout`, а в `GridView`, а то приложение на 10-й картинке(в лучшем случае) упадет с `OutOfMemory`